# Map in map - C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to read from a txt file with the next format:

> Book_Name,price,length,genere

and I am not sure what is the database I should use.
Because I just finished a project in python doing something similar with reading from a file I thought I'll use here [python definitions] in a dictionary in which each key would be the book name and each value would be another dictionary.
In the inside dictionary  keys will be fixed [after I read the 1st line of the text I could save it in a list or maybe insert fixed order in the 1st place when I first create the container] meaning 'price' and 'length' will always be the keys and for each key i'll have its own value readn from the text.

My question is how  I build such thing in CPP and is it the case where i should use multimap or think in that direction?

Comment: So... you're looking for something like `map[bookName]["price"] = priceVal` and `map[bookName]["length"] = lengthVal` Right? If so then i would indeed say look into [maps](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/). But i would go with the structure solution of the two answers below. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would actually use a class to represent this.

```
class Book
{
public:
    Book() : m_name{}, m_price{}, m_length{}, m_genre{} {}

    Book(std::string const& name, double price, unsigned long length, std::string const& genre)
    : m_name{name}, m_price{price}, m_length{length}, m_genre{genre}
    { }       

private:
    std::string m_name;
    double m_price;
    unsigned long m_length;
    std::string m_genre;
};
```

You can then use a `std::map` (which is like a Python `dict`) to lookup a book by it's name

```
std::map<std::string, Book> library;
```

Comment: How will he access anything in the book after he's constructed one?

Comment: By either making the members public or creating setters/getters.

Comment: Both of you and @scohe001 gave the same solution pretty much but it wouldn't sort out my problems of getting the details of the book efficiently after I created the database[which might contain up to a few hundreds of different books].
with the addition of a map contains key as book names and value as the whole book class object I think this might work pretty good. my only question Is will the creation of this database will take more time then using a map in map style?
anyway this is simpler to my idea so I'll definitely try it out, thanks.

Comment: @maor This way you'll have a map of N items. If you go the map in map route, you'll wind up with one large map with N smaller maps, and inside of each of those, you'll have 3 smaller maps for your 3 values (c++ can't mix values in the same map), resulting in 4N maps (4 for each book). Asymptotically, `4N = O(N)` and `N = O(N)` as far as space complexity goes

Answer (score 2):

C++ is an Object Oriented language, take advantage of that!

You can create your own book object! (if all you're doing is storing those values, you can use a struct)

```
struct Book {
    std::string name;
    double price;
    unsigned length;
    std::string genre;

    Book(const std::string &name, double price, unsigned length, const std::string &genre)
        : name(name), price(price), length(length), genre(genre) { }
}
```

So now when you want to make a new book you can do:

```
Book b("Wise Man's Fear", 24.99, 1000, Fantasy);
std::cout << "My book is: " << b.name << std::end;
```

Comment: yes but I dont need only a way to save them I also need a way to get book details efficiently.

Comment: @maor how you store the books is up to you, whether you use a set or a hash map or a vector, I'm only trying to illustrate for you how to put all of that data into a single usable object so that now you'll be at a point where you can solve the rest yourself.

Comment: only now  I understand where you aimed to.havn't thought even to approach it this way. 
Thanks.